# Extracting sub-strings in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cygwin, filenames

I'm using *cygwin* on *Windows 7*. I want to loop through a folder consisting of about 10,000 files and perform a signal processing tool's operation on each file. The problem is that the files names have some excess characters that are not compatible with the operation. Hence, I need to extract just a certain part of the file names.

For example if the file name is `abc123456_justlike.txt.rna` I need to use `abc123456_justlike.txt`. How should I write a loop to go through each file and perform the operation on the shortened file names?

I tried the `cut - b1-10` command but that doesn't let my tool perform the necessary operation. I'd appreciate help with this problem

Comment: This question should probably move to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Strongly disagree. Just because you are using shell tools like `cut`, `sed`, `awk`, or `perl`, does not mean that it is not a programming question. It most definitely is such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some shell scripting, using the ${NAME%TAIL} parameter substitution: the contents of variable NAME are expanded, but any suffix material which matches the TAIL glob pattern is chopped off.

```
$ NAME=abc12345.txt.rna
$ echo ${NAME%.rna}  #

# process all files in the directory, taking off their .rna suffix
$ for x in *; do signal_processing_tool ${x%.rna} ; done
```

If there are variations among the file names, you can classify them with a case:

```
for x in * ; do
  case $x in 
     *.rna ) 
        # do something with .rna files
        ;;
     *.txt )
        # do something else with .txt files
        ;;
     * )
        # default catch-all-else case
        ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I like the first solution you proposed. Here is my updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573953/filename-manipulation-in-cygwin

Answer (score 2):

Try `sed`:

```
echo a.b.c | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

The `s` command in `sed` performs a search-and-replace operation, in this case it replaces the regular expression `\.[^.]*$` (meaning: a dot, followed by any number of non-dots, at the end of the string) with the empty string.

If you are not yet familiar with regular expressions, this is a good point to learn them. I find manipulating string using regular expressions much more straightforward than using tools like `cut` (or their equivalents).

Comment: Why did you escape the dot within the square-bracketed character class? That is not needed; it has different rules.  BTW, if you prefer the fancier regexes from Perl, you could just say `perl -pe 's/\.[^.]*$//'` as the equivalent, although here in this case it makes no difference. With fancier patterns, the `sed` syntax using BREs gets a bit long-winded.

Comment: Thanks, edited. I don't prefer Perl to anything, and I'd rather refrain from starting a flame war here, too :-) The basics of regular expressions are almost the same in most of the regexp dialects. Also, there's `sed -r`.

Comment: The thing is that `sed` by default, and per the standard, uses **Basic Regular Expressions**, wherein you must backslash-escape things like `\(` or `\|` or `\+` to get them to be metacharacters. If you the `-E` flag to GNU `sed`, that will switch to the **Extended Regular Expressions** that Perl uses. However, Perl is more portable because there are not versions of it that do not understand EREs; alas with `sed`, there are.

Comment: Good point. Lucky me, I have yet to meet a `sed` that doesn't understand the `-r` switch. Which OSes do you have in mind? And what makes you so sure that `perl` will be installed there?

Comment: I have yet to meet a `sed` that *does* understand a `-r` switch. Certainly the one on Mac OS does not, although it does grok `-E`. The one on OpenBSD understands neither, being a POSIX sed; same on AIX.

Comment: I certainly love my Ubuntu with its GNU `sed` that understands both `-r` and `-E`. Bht this becomes slightly off-topic, not sure if the OP benefits.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8549/discussion-between-user946850-and-tchrist)

Comment: I'm going to post a new question, specifying the problem more clearly. Your solution gives me the same results as `cut`. I'll post the link to the question here~

Comment: That's what I was wondering. Please use at least the tags "cygwin" and "shell", possibly something along "string manipulation".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract the list of filenames from a directory use the below command.

```
ls -ltr | awk -F " " '{print $9}' | cut -c1-10
```